# Apache Common FileUtils Read XML file into String

Tags: xml-parsing, apache-commons, fileutils

I have stored SOAP XML file into local machine now to validate that XML i need to load that file and extract the XML from SOAP body to validate it.

SOAP XML

```
<SOAP:Envelope>
    <SOAP:Body>
        <request>
             <Login>
                <Username>abc</Username>
                <Password>abc</Password>
             </Login>
        </request>
    </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

I need to extract the <Login> XML from above SOAP request.
I am using FileUtils to read file into string. when i read the file using that it also read the characters like \n\t\t etc means it consider the newline and tab which is in the XML formatted file.

i extract the child node from XML as string using below code.

```
InputStream requestXMLInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(soapRequestXML.getBytes());
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
String requestXMLBody = "";
Document doc = null;
try {
    dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    doc = dBuilder.parse(requestXMLInputStream);        
    NodeList requestNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName(parentTagName);
    Node node = requestNodeList.item(0);
    DOMImplementationLS domImplLS = (DOMImplementationLS) doc.getImplementation();
    LSSerializer serializer = domImplLS.createLSSerializer();
    if(node != null && node.getFirstChild() != null)
          requestXMLBody = serializer.writeToString(node.getFirstChild());
} catch (SAXException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
}catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
}

return requestXMLBody;
```

How can i read an XML file in without these characters.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Using string manipulation for reading XML documents is a well-tested recipe for headache and frustration. Use only published XML API's for that.

The general approach would be:

1) Assuming that the SOAP XML is stored in a file, use the JAXP API to parse the XML into a `Document` object.

2) Navigate to the `Login` element using XPath (use the standard Java XPath API, included in the JDK).

3) Once you have a reference to the `Login` element, use a JAXP `Transformer` to serialize the `Login` element into a string.

(Step (1) would change if the SOAP packet is received through usage of one of the standard web services API's. You mentioned that the SOAP packet is given as stored in a file)